# What is wrong with my code? It is not working properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, deployment

This is the line of code I am using to show the blog data wrt email but it is showing `cannot GET /myblog` :

```
app.get("/myblog/:e_mail", async (req, res) => {
  const requestedEmail = req.params.e_mail;
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email: requestedEmail });

    if (!user) {
      throw new Error("User not found");
    }

    if (!user.selfBlog) {
      throw new Error("User does not have a self-blog post");
    }

    const post = user.selfBlog;

    res.render("myblog", {
      title: post.title,
      content: post.content
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching post:", error);
    res.status(404).render("error", { errorMessage: "Post not found!" });
  }
});
```

I tried to get the data in my DB but got the error specified and it is my first time writing here so sorry for any mistake and as English is not my first language so sorry for any error in my English.

Comment: Please past the error or mention the error type in the title to help find easily

Answer (score 1):

If there is another route set before this one using the base `/myblog` it will default to that. Try changing your route naming, This should solve your problem.

Now this shouldn't resolve your problem, but always give it a shot.
try removing the first '/' from the route:

```
app.get("myblog/:e_mail", async (req, res) => {...
```

Also, this route won't work without a `e_mail` param set. I'm not that familiar with express but the last I tried it, it would give me a `cannot get '/routebase'` error.